# Listcell removes Starting Spaces

Tags: zk

When I create `new Listcell("       a")` I can only see output as `"a"` instead of `"      a"` , does listcell removes the starting spaces from the label of listcell...if so how can I avoid it from doing it.?  I am doing this in ZK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Listcell lc=new Listcell();
Label lb=new Label(str);
lb.setPre(true);
lc.appendChild(lb);
```

Did solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

try to put "%20" instead of " "